# SonarQube Scanner for MS build with Jenkins failed in the end step

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

These are the final logs:

The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.

Possible causes:

1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)

Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.

Comment: Build your project with latest msbuild you have. Sometimes, I used to solve the problem by building first, then running sonar sequence as usual. This also may require to install reference assemblies and specify path to them in your sonar sequence file. Additionally, it may require you to split project analysis to smaller batches, e.g. analyze by folders. More additional logs would help, especially your sonar.bat file

Comment: This error comes when I am running these commands using Jenkins Job. And especially the end command gives error a number of times.

Comment: Why don't you at least show what you're doing? Telepaths are on vacations right now.